# How can I disable react StrictMode on remix dev?

Tags: reactjs, remix

I'm trying to build a remix application, and it seems all of my components are loaded twice. Looking at [remix's code](https://github.com/remix-run/remix/search?q=StrictMode&type=code) it seem like they add a React StrictMode component when rendering from dev (note that building and rendering via `npm build && npm start` does solve the issue).

The issue I have with this is that I'm getting 429 errors from a third-party service I'm using because of the multiple simultaneous calls.

Is there any way to disable react strict mode and still use `npm dev` instead of having to rebuild and start for every change I make ?

I would imagine there could be some flag to `remix dev` or some environment variable to set, but I couldn't find anything yet

For the record, my `/app/root.tsx` does *not* contain a strict mode so I don't see how to remove it

```
import { ChakraProvider } from '@chakra-ui/react'
import type { MetaFunction } from '@remix-run/node'
import {
  Links,
  LiveReload,
  Meta,
  Outlet,
  Scripts,
  ScrollRestoration,
} from '@remix-run/react'

export const meta: MetaFunction = () => ({
  charset: 'utf-8',
  title: '...',
  viewport: 'width=device-width,initial-scale=1',
})

export default function App() {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <Meta />
        <Links />
      </head>
      <body>
        <ChakraProvider>
          <Outlet />
        </ChakraProvider>
        <ScrollRestoration />
        <Scripts />
        <LiveReload />
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, I found it.
So remix started to hide the `app/entry.client.tsx` (where the strict mode is enabled). It can be ejected by running `npx remix reveal`

source: https://github.com/remix-run/remix/releases/tag/remix%401.14.0